# Cronjob or batch php file execution

Tags: php

i've 30 or more php script thats must be executed daily.
But i don't want to create cronjobs for every php file.
So, i've looked for a php script that gets every file in directory and includes in a page:

```
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename){ if ($filename!='work.php') } {
    include($filename);
}
```

But when i try to include all files in same page, my page is getting slow and i tought it'll exhaust the server.
Is there any way to create cronjob for executing all php files in a directory or is there any way to execute all files in one php file one by one?
So, i hope i could explain myself, any ideas?

Comment: You can create *one* cronjob for it all, by using `&&` e.g. `00 00 * * * script1.php && script2.php && script3.php` etc.

Comment: thanks noted that one, but filenames will change in the future.

Comment: just create a single page that functions as an auto loader assuming all your stuff is OO based failing that do it your way.  the speed issue is nothing to do with your cron its to do with just how it works. if one script takes 10 seconds and you have 30 scripts taking 10 seconds then ofc its going to take 300 seconds.  optimise your sql queries, use index's, tidy up your code etc.  One thing you don't have to worry about is script time out when running a job on a cron :)

Comment: thanks for the info, but scripts confused when i tried that way.. i need to execute all files one by one i guess..